# Problem when mounting Windows drive

Tags: system-installation, mount, drive, lock, microsoft

After I installed Ubuntu on my device I couldn't access my Windows SSD. It should be using a passphrase, and I have no idea about it.

[image: auth pic]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: What drives and partitions do you have? What exactly are you doing to get this request for a passphrase? Does this occur in Ubuntu or Windows?

Comment: Is you Windows drive encryted with Bitlocker?

Comment: my bad, I'm not checking the drive is encrypted or not before I installed Linux, should I reinstall windows to decrypt it?

Comment: I'd find your BitLocker recovery key in your Microsoft account and try using that as the passphrase.